# converting HSLS gives error

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, hlsl, tools

I'm using the following parser: 
https://github.com/unknownworlds/hlslparser

I also have the following code:

```
/*
 * Bo Sun, Columbia University, All rights reserved
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Permission to use, copy, or modify this software and its documentation
 * for educational and research purposes only and without fee is hereby
 * granted.  
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * 
 * March. 2005
 */


struct frag2app {
  float4 color : COLOR;
};

/*auxiliary functions*/
float A0(float I0, float beta, float Dsv, float gamma)
{
    const float PI = 3.1415926535;
    return (beta*I0*1*(-beta*Dsv*cos(gamma)))/(2*PI*Dsv*sin(gamma));
}
float A1(float beta, float Dsv, float gamma)
{
    return beta*Dsv*sin(gamma);
}

/*functions to compute each radiance component seperately*/
float AirLight(float lightIntensity, 
        float beta, 
        float Dsv, 
        float Dvp, 
        float gammasv,
        samplerRECT F,
        float f_XOffset, 
        float f_XScale, 
        float f_YOffset,        
        float f_YScale)
{
    const float PI = 3.1415926535;
    float u = A1(beta, Dsv, gammasv);
    float v1 = 0.25*PI+0.5*atan((Dvp-Dsv*cos(gammasv))/(Dsv*sin(gammasv)));
    float v2 = 0.5*gammasv;

    float4 f_1=texRECT(F, float2((v1-f_XOffset)*f_XScale, (u-f_YOffset)*f_YScale));
    float4 f_2=texRECT(F, float2((v2-f_XOffset)*f_XScale, (u-f_YOffset)*f_YScale));
    return A0(lightIntensity, beta, Dsv, gammasv)*(f_1.x-f_2.x);
}
float Diffuse(float lightIntensity, 
        float beta, 
        float Kd,
        float Dsp, 
        float Dvp, 
        float thetas,
        samplerRECT G_0,
        float g_0XOffset,
        float g_0XScale, 
        float g_0YOffset,
        float g_0YScale)
{
    const float PI = 3.1415926535;

    float t1 = exp(-beta*Dsp)*max(cos(thetas),0)/Dsp;
    float4 t2 = beta*texRECT(G_0, float2((beta*Dsp-g_0XOffset)*g_0XScale, (thetas-g_0YOffset)*g_0YScale))/(2*PI);
    return (t1+t2.x)*exp(-beta*Dvp)*Kd*lightIntensity/Dsp;
}
float Specular(float lightIntensity, 
        float beta, 
        float Ks,   
        float Dsp, 
        float Dvp,  
        float thetas_,
        samplerRECT G_20,
        float g_20XOffset, 
        float g_20XScale, 
        float g_20YOffset, 
        float g_20YScale)
{
    const float PI=3.1415926535;

    float t1 = exp(-beta*Dsp)*pow(max(cos(thetas_),0),20)/Dsp;
    float4 t2 = beta*texRECT(G_20, float2((beta*Dsp-g_20XOffset)*g_20XScale, (thetas_-g_20YOffset)*g_20YScale))/(2*PI);
    return (t1+t2.x)*exp(-beta*Dvp)*Ks*lightIntensity/Dsp;
}

/*main function*/
frag2app fmain( float4 objPos : TEXCOORD3,
        float3 normal : TEXCOORD4,
        float4 color : COLOR,

        uniform float3 lightPosition,
        uniform float3 viewPosition,
        uniform float lightIntensity,
        uniform float beta,
        uniform float Kd,
        uniform float Ks,

        uniform samplerRECT F,
        uniform float f_XOffset,
        uniform float f_XScale,
        uniform float f_YOffset,
        uniform float f_YScale,

        uniform samplerRECT G_0,
        uniform float g_0XOffset,
        uniform float g_0XScale,
        uniform float g_0YOffset,
        uniform float g_0YScale,

        uniform samplerRECT G_20,
        uniform float g_20XOffset,
        uniform float g_20XScale,
        uniform float g_20YOffset,
        uniform float g_20YScale)
{
    beta=4;
    frag2app OUT;
    const float PI = 3.1415926535;

    /*preparing parameters*/
    float3 N = normalize(normal);
    float3 V = normalize(objPos.xyz-viewPosition);
    float3 S = normalize(lightPosition-viewPosition);
    float3 L = normalize(lightPosition-objPos.xyz);
    float3 RV = reflect(V, N);

    float Dvp = length(viewPosition-objPos.xyz);
    float Dsv = length(lightPosition-viewPosition);
    float Dsp = length(lightPosition-objPos.xyz);
    float gamma = acos(dot(S, V));
    float thetas = acos(dot(N, L));
    float thetas_ = acos(dot(L, RV));

    /*compute airlight, diffuse and specular color seperately using our model in the paper*/
    float airlight = AirLight(lightIntensity, beta, Dsv, Dvp, gamma, F, f_XOffset,f_XScale, f_YOffset,f_YScale);
    float diffuse = Diffuse(lightIntensity, beta, Kd, Dsp, Dvp, thetas, G_0, g_0XOffset,g_0XScale, g_0YOffset,g_0YScale);
    float specular = Specular(lightIntensity, beta, Ks, Dsp, Dvp, thetas_, G_20, g_20XOffset, g_20XScale, g_20YOffset, g_20YScale);

    /*diffuse color-red, airlight color-white, specular color-white*/
    OUT.color = float4(diffuse+airlight+specular,specular+airlight,specular+airlight, 0);
    return OUT;
}
```

that I want to convert to GLSL, however this gives the following error:

However this gives the following error:
ERROR /path/wip.fragmentshader(21) : Undeclared identifier 'exp'
ERROR: Parsing failed, aborting

removing the exp and replacing it with exp (any way to easily include the math?)
gives the error 
ERROR /path/fragmentshader(34) : Expected declaration
ERROR: Parsing failed, aborting

lines 34 is `samplerRECT F`, any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Does this compile if you override the diffuse and specular calculations? float diffuse = 1; float specular = 1;

Comment: It will the complain about the second problem except with a different line number.